# Remove numeric values from an object where the values are all strings but a mix of letter and numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have to call an api that returns an array of objects:

```
"supervisors": [
    {
        "jurisdiction": "u",
        "lastName": "Olson",
        "firstName": "Karson"
    },
    {
        "jurisdiction": "9",
        "lastName": "Heller",
        "firstName": "Robbie"
    },
    {
        "jurisdiction": "b",
        "lastName": "Cremin",
        "firstName": "Elijah"
    },
]
```

The supervisors must be sorted in alphabetical order, first by jurisdiction, then my last name, finally by first name.
Then  Numeric jurisdictions should be removed from the response.

I sorted alphabetically by:

```
supervisorsObj.sort((a, b) => {
      a.jurisdiction.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.jurisdiction.toLowerCase());
    });
```

But how do I remove Numeric jurisdictions if they are all strings?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use regular expressions, e.g

```
filtered = data.supervisors.filter(s => !/^\d+$/.test(s.jurisdiction))
```

will only remove jurisdictions that consists entirely of digits.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will first filter out all numeric `.jurisdiction` entries and will sort the remaining entries in a case-insensitive manner according to jurisdiction, lastName, firstName:

```js
const supervisors= [
{
    "jurisdiction": "u",
    "lastName": "Olson",
    "firstName": "Karson"
},
{
    "jurisdiction": "9",
    "lastName": "Heller",
    "firstName": "Robbie"
},
{
    "jurisdiction": "b",
    "lastName": "Cremin",
    "firstName": "Elijah"
},
{
    "jurisdiction": "b",
    "lastName": "Cremmin",
    "firstName": "Elijah"
},
{
    "jurisdiction": "b",
    "lastName": "Cremin",
    "firstName": "Daniel"
},
{
    "jurisdiction": "b",
    "lastName": "Cremin",
    "firstName": "eddie"
}
];

const res=supervisors.filter(s=>isNaN(parseFloat(s.jurisdiction)))
  .sort((a,b)=>{
      let ab=0;
      ["jurisdiction","lastName","firstName"].some(p=>ab=a[p].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[p].toLowerCase()));
      return ab;
});

console.log(res);
```

The actual comparisons take place in the inner `.some()` loop. The loop will stop processing as soon as it generates a result `ab` that is not equal to zero.